# Device not recognized

Tags: android

My device does not appear in the device chooser to in Android studios even though I hv checked the USB debugging,  and all the suggestion I find here does not work for me. Thank you in advance

Comment: Is your Android Studios running under Mac OS?

Answer (score 0):

which phone and rom dou you have? any custom rom? Has it ever worked?
try a shot on this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZu4GDf963M

so, in video you can see how to configure phone and how find driver Android ADB Interface (something like C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\usb_drivers).

Good luck